# Web2py Query Returning No Result

Tags: python, sql, web2py

I have 2 tables in Web2py

- `auth_user` (standard table)
- `customer` (I defined this table)

When an entry is made for customer using a form, a value is placed in the `customer` table in a `company_id` field using currently logged in user (that creates the entries), `id` (from the `auth_user` table).  This is done via `auth.user_id`.

Now, I am trying to query the `customer` table using the `auth.user_id` of the currently logged in user to pull up all entries created by the currently logged in user.

I am doing this

```
def viewcustomers():

    rows = db.customer(db.customer.company_id == auth.user_id)
    print rows
```

In my view, I have

```
{{=viewcustomers}}
```

The only result I am getting is 'None'.

Does anyone know whats going on?

Answer (score 0):

Why not have your controller's viewcustomers() function return a dictionary with 'viewcustomers' as a key?

```
def viewcustomers():

  rows = db.customer(db.customer.company_id == auth.user_id).select()
  return dict(viewcustomers = rows) # or whatever instead of 'rows'
```

Also, if you're performing the db query based on the current customer, should that be session.auth.user.id, instead of auth.user_id?

EDIT: added '.select()', subsequent to conversation below.

Comment: By adding the return dict(viewcustomers = rows) line it seems to be working. Brilliant. However, it is only returning one result when there are more in the table. @Boa, do you know how to have it show more than one result?

Comment: @user2073336 - Try to replace the above 'rows = ...' line with this: "rows = db.customer(db.customer.company_id == auth.user_id).select()".

Comment: Note, `auth.user_id` is the same as `session.auth.user.id` (though the former will simply return `None` in case there is no `session.auth.user.id` rather than raising an exception).

Comment: @Anthony - thanks - that's awesome. Would've saved me much typing, copying, and pasting, had I known that sooner!

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `print` in order to generate HTML output. The `print` command will simply print to the console. In order for the view to be executed, your function must return a dictionary (as it is, your function doesn't return anything, which is why the browser shows "None").

Also, the `db.mytable(query)` syntax only returns the first matching record. If you want all records, you must use the `db(query).select()` syntax.

So, your function should look like this:

```
def viewcustomers():
    rows = db(db.customer.company_id == auth.user_id).select()
    return dict(viewcustomers=rows)
```

Note, if you insert a `Rows` object in a view as you have, it will be displayed via `SQLTABLE` by default.